# Reactjs Onclick Button to sort by day, month or year?

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering how to create an onClick function where you are able to sort an array of data into their respected dates.
Such as Day, Month, and year.

desired output would be *onClick today* only today's date will show up.

My output currently is `["12/19/2020"]` and

```
2: {id: 3, type: "Groceries", spent: 100, date: "12/19/2020"}
```

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
     const onClickDay = (date) => {
    const getExpenseSavings = () => {
      getAllData().then((res) => {
        setSave(res[1]);
        setExpense(res[2]);
      });
    };
    const getSaveDates = save.map((item) => {
      const d = item.date;
      const saveConverted = DateTime.fromISO(d).toLocaleString();
      return { ...item, date: saveConverted };
    });

    const getExpenseDate = expense.map((item) => {
      const d = item.date;
      const expenseConverted = DateTime.fromISO(d).toLocaleString();
      return { ...item, date: expenseConverted };
    });

    setData([[getExpenseDate], [getSaveDates]]);
  };

//Where I'm filtering the dates by my onClick...
  const filterDay = () => {
    if (data !== null) {
      const results = data.filter((date) => {
        return setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
        setDay(date.getDate());
        setYear(date.getFullYear());
      });
      setFilterResults(results);
    }
  };
```

And my Hooks...

```
    const [year, setYear] = useState([d.getFullYear()]);
  const [month, setMonth] = useState([d.getMonth() + 1]);
  const [day, setDay] = useState([d.getDate()]);

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
  const [filterResults, setFilterResults] = useState([]);

  const [data, setData] = useState([null]); //this is where my dates are stored atm...
  const [expense, setExpense] = useState(null);
  const [save, setSave] = useState(null);

  const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false);
```

Thanks in advance! Please help...

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

How to sort an array by date value in JavaScript

Find out how to sort an array of items by date value in JavaScript
Say you have an array of objects like this, which contains a set of date objects:

```
const activities = [
  { title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2019-06-28') },
  { title: 'Shopping', date: new Date('2019-06-10') },
  { title: 'Trekking', date: new Date('2019-06-22') }
]
```

You want to sort those activities by the `date` property.
You can use the `sort()` method of `Array`, which takes a callback function, which takes as parameters 2 objects contained in the array (which we call `a` and `b`):

```
const sortedActivities = activities.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
```

When we return a positive value, the function communicates to `sort()` that the object `b` takes precedence in sorting over the object `a`. Returning a negative value will do the opposite.

The `sort()` method returns a new sorted array, but it also sorts the original array in place. Thus, both the `sortedActivities` and `activities` arrays are now sorted. One option to protect the original array from being modified is to use the `slice()` method to create a copy of the array prior to sorting, as follows:

```
const sortedActivities = activities.slice().sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
```

### Read this:

### https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-sort-array-by-date-javascript/

### https://gist.github.com/onpubcom/1772996

### [How to sort an array by a date property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property)